# "C"."CLIENT_FNAME": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    ch.charter_nbr,
    ch.client_nbr,
    to_char(CASE WHEN c.client_lname IS NULL THEN '-' WHEN c.client_fname IS NULL THEN '-' END),
    total_charter_cost

FROM(
    SELECT
    ch.charter_nbr,
    ch.client_nbr,
    SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 * (cl_ata - cl_atd)) AS total_charter_cost,
    AVG(SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 * (cl_ata - cl_atd))) AS average_total_cost
    
    
FROM 
    MH.charter ch JOIN MH.client c ON ch.client_nbr = c.client_nbr
    JOIN MH.charter_leg cl ON ch.charter_nbr = cl.charter_nbr

GROUP BY
    ch.charter_nbr,
    ch.client_nbr
    )

WHERE 
    total_charter_cost <= average_total_cost

ORDER BY
    total_charter_cost DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it as I don't have your columns, but - I'd try with something like this. Read comments within code.

```
SELECT x.charter_nbr,                               --> 5. use inline view's alias, not
       x.client_nbr,                                --     tables' ones. They aren't
       x.total_charter_cost,                        --     accessible here
       x.your_case_column                           --> 3. select it here
FROM(SELECT ch.charter_nbr,
            ch.client_nbr,
            SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 *(cl_ata - cl_atd))      AS total_charter_cost,
            AVG(SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 *(cl_ata - cl_atd))) AS average_total_cost,
            --
            CASE                                    --> 1. CASE goes into an inline view
              WHEN c.client_lname IS NULL THEN
                '-'
              WHEN c.client_fname IS NULL THEN
                '-'
            END your_case_column                    --> 2. this is CASE expression's alias
     FROM mh.charter ch
     JOIN mh.client         c ON ch.client_nbr = c.client_nbr
     JOIN mh.charter_leg    cl ON ch.charter_nbr = cl.charter_nbr
     GROUP BY ch.charter_nbr,
              ch.client_nbr,
              CASE
                WHEN c.client_lname IS NULL THEN
                  '-'
                WHEN c.client_fname IS NULL THEN
                  '-'
              END
    ) x                                            --> 4. inline view's alias is "x"
WHERE total_charter_cost <= average_total_cost
ORDER BY total_charter_cost DESC;
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer so we can learn something?

Comment: Sure, @Codo. Re-read my 2nd sentence which says "Read comments within code."

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outer query and a subquery. The aliases that you're using inside the subquery cannot be used in the outer query. So, 'ch', 'c' will not work at all in the outer query. So, the first thing you can do is removing these aliases.

Now that you'd have removed the aliases, you'd realize your subquery is returning only these columns - charter_nbr, ch.client_nbr, total_charter_cost, average_total_cost. And you also need client_lname and client_fname in the outer query. So, you would need to add these as well to the subquery. And if you're doing that, you'd need to add these to the GROUP BY as well.

```
SELECT 
    charter_nbr,
    client_nbr,
    to_char(CASE WHEN client_lname IS NULL THEN '-' WHEN client_fname IS NULL THEN '-' END),
    total_charter_cost

FROM(
    SELECT
    ch.charter_nbr,
    ch.client_nbr,
    SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 * (cl_ata - cl_atd)) AS total_charter_cost,
    AVG(SUM(charter_cost_per_hour * 24 * (cl_ata - cl_atd))) AS average_total_cost
    c.client_lname , c.client_fname
    
FROM 
    MH.charter ch JOIN MH.client c ON ch.client_nbr = c.client_nbr
    JOIN MH.charter_leg cl ON ch.charter_nbr = cl.charter_nbr

GROUP BY
    ch.charter_nbr,
    ch.client_nbr,
    c.client_lname , c.client_fname
    )

WHERE 
    total_charter_cost <= average_total_cost

ORDER BY
    total_charter_cost DESC;
```

HTH!